# Making request to a redirect in my laravel backend api from angular frontend returns CORS error

Tags: angular, rest, cors, laravel-5.4

I have an angular route that makes request to an endpoint to the backend, backend and front end both running on localhost.
backend : localhost:8000
frontend : localhost:4200

backend endpoint:

```
'user/github'
```

Now when angular frontend makes request to this backend endpoint following controller is called.

```
public function makeRequest(Request $request)
    {        
        //return response()->json(['message'=>'hi'],'200');
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => 'c98f06e52785cdf675ec',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/api/oauth2/github',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => '*'
        ]);
        //return response()->json(['message'=>$query],'200');
        return redirect('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
    }
```

Now most probably due to presence of redirect in my controller I m  getting CORS error.
How to resolve this issue.
Is redirect being done this way even allowed..??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include "access origin allowed" header in your frontend request, if you have a node.js backend I suggest you make some changes in the setting of your node.js codes as well, please ensure that you are doing that in the test environment.

read this link which will give you insight of what is needed when you make a request and what is CORS all about.

#### [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

read this paragraph from MDN documentation,

> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>
> A returned resource may have one Access-Control-Allow-Origin header,
> with the following syntax:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  | * The origin parameter
> specifies a URI that may access the resource. The browser must enforce
> this. For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as
> a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource."

Comment: I have already inluded CORS package in my backend. Any Domain can access domain at which the backend is hosted. The problem is with redirect.